# How can I have Behat create content with an address field properly filled?

Tags: testing, 9

I'm writting a Behat test, where I'm triying to create a content that uses a field address, generated by Address Module. I'm using Drupal 9.0.7, Address Module 1.9.0 and behat 3.8.1. My goal is to create this type of content in my scenario; I'm using a behat table for this, and a *Given* statement like the following.

```
Given place content:

  | title   | field_address:country_code |field_address:address_line1 | status |
  |<<title>>| es                         | Behat test street          | 1      |
```

field_address:country_code and field address:address_line1 are sub-fields of the address field.

This way of naming the sub-fields doesn't seeem to work.

How should I have to name the table headers, in order to make Behat create content with a field address properly filled?

Comment: Have you already tried it in a format like at the bottom of the opening post there: https://github.com/ymcatwincities/openy/pull/237#issue-111160763

Comment: `| title | field_address:country_code | :address_line1 | status |` maybe?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work. It gives me "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in vendor/drupal/drupal-driver/src/Drupal/Driver/Fields/Drupal8/AddressHandler.php line 54".

Comment: Is it maybe important, that there's a space between the pipe character and the field name? Because there the space is missing: `|field_address:address_line1` and here as well: `|<<title>>|`. Is `<<title>>` some kind of placeholder or wildcard? And is this address field a multi-value field?

Comment: I don't think the space is important but I will try it to assure that that's not the case. And no, <<title>> it's not a wildcard. It doesn't matter here because title works properly,and when I post the question, I didn't pay attention to it, and place it as a wildcard to expess that it's not important. Sorry if Iconfuse you. I will try to put the spaces to see if it works. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but here is the proper way of doing it.

```
And "CONTENT_TYPE" content:
  | title          | field_address                    |
  | Bert and Ernie | address_line1: Sesame Street 123 |
```

The supported options are:

```
$addressFields = [
  'given_name',
  'additional_name',
  'family_name',
  'organization',
  'address_line1',
  'address_line2',
  'postal_code',
  'sorting_code',
  'locality',
  'administrative_area',
  'country_code',
];
```

Which can be found in `\Drupal\Driver\Fields\Drupal8\AddressHandler::expand`

Currently there is a [bug](https://github.com/jhedstrom/DrupalDriver/issues/206) in `drupal/drupal-driver` so if you are using composer (which you should) you can apply the following patch. Otherwise you will get an error like "Notice: Undefined offset: 0"

```
"drupal/drupal-driver" : {
    "Issue #206: Address field in Drupal 8 (PR: 236/240)": "https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/jhedstrom/DrupalDriver/pull/240.diff"
}
```